# How much additional space would repair database require

Tags: mongodb

I've aksed [this question in mongodb google group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/oi6S-LKfTrs/discussion), in absence of any reply posting it here.

We have a single node mongo (version 2.0.1) instance. We are running  out of disk space even after daily archiving as mongo doesn't return  the space back to the OS and tries to use it itself. Currently our  setup has become very sparse with around 50% space lying idle. You can  see that data + index size is around 1170 GB while storage size is  around 2158 GB and file size is around 2368 GB.

```
db.stats()    
{  
    "db" : "default",            
    "collections" : 106,  
    "objects" : 553988389,  
    "avgObjSize" : 2094.1392962010254,  
    "dataSize" : NumberLong("1160128855044"),  
    "storageSize" : NumberLong("2315777236208"),  
    "numExtents" : 1487,  
    "indexes" : 107,  
    "indexSize" : 97914435136,  
    "fileSize" : NumberLong("2543459500032"),  
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,  
    "ok" : 1  
}
```

We want to reclaim the space and as this is not a mission critical  system (its like a dumping yard for logs) can sustain a downtime. We  don't want to spend on creating a replica set also we are in a  physical datacenter hence will prefer not to attach additional disk  only for repairing database.
I want to understand :-
-How much free disk space is required for repair database
-How much space can we hope to recover after repair database
-Around how much time should it take to repair database.
-If at all repair database keeps going on, is it safe to just kill it  and restart the database.

Bulk of our data lie in a single collection so whether compact collection would be better than repair database.

Comment: Repair can require up to 2X space.

Comment: 2X of data size or storage size?

Comment: Repair will do a ``mongodump`` and ``mongorestore`` and for that it requires twice the disk space your database is using i.e. it needs space to store the old and new database files. To avoid that you could manually do a ``mongodump``, delete the database files and then run ``mongorestore``. Alternatively, if you just need to reclaim unused space you can run ``compact`` (make sure you have 2GB free space).

Comment: thanks @diliop but `compact` won't return the space back to OS. will it start using the freed up space much more efficiently?

Comment: Compact does free up space, it basically, on collection level, rewrites your extents to defragment them removing the $deletedlists in the process which is the thing that can cause fragmentation by holding space to be reused

Answer (score 3):

First I would recommend you to upgrade from 2.0.1. At least to 2.0.7 if not 2.2.2. 
Repair takes 2x file size. 
You should end up with slightly larger than your data size as your file size. 
How long it takes depends on system resources and how busy your system is. 
Compact doesn't free space on disk - it just defragments within the data file.

In 2.2.x you can use 
[collMod](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/)

command to set usePowerOf2Sizes to reduce file fragmentation. e.g insert 800 byte document and 1024 bytes will be allocated. Delete that doc and insert a 900 byte doc, now the 1024 space can be reused. Without this maybe only 850 bytes would have been allocated and new free space would have been allocated for the 900 byte document.

killing repairDatabase should be ok - files are copied to new location, defragg'd then copied back in on completion but you would have to test it to be sure :)

Comment: Thanks @gregor At present we are archiving regularly but mongo is not able to utilize the freed space properly which you can see by the difference in data+index size and storage size. If we go ahead and `compact` the data then will it start utilizing the space (the free space which is with mongo) more efficiently? As per upgrade, currently we don't want to invest any bandwidth as the full solution is going to be replaced in a couple of months or so. Also as @diliop has suggested whether 2GB would be sufficient for `compact`

Comment: @ApoorvaGaurav Hi, I've seen people who use MongoDB in production with big writes and reads doing compact on a regular bases like every week. They even wrote a script like this one to do it automatically and not doing the repair cause it takes like forever and needs x2 of the storage. Check this out: http://blog.parse.com/2013/03/26/always-be-compacting/ and here is the code on github: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Ops/blob/master/tools/mongo_compact.rb