# How to free up disk space on MongoDB without repair

Tags: mongodb, disk

I have a mongoDB with 24TB of data, which is almost out of space (there is slightly less than 0.7TB left).

I tried deleting many records, but that doesn't seem to help. No data on the disk is freed (which I understand is normal), but I would have at least expected Mongo to write new data on the freed space, and not continue to consume new disk space.

The current stats of my biggest collection (which takes up more than 19TB) are:

```
{
    "count" : 19165555853,
    "size" : NumberLong("18762737940528"),
    "avgObjSize" : 978.9821951650337,
    "storageSize" : NumberLong("19157960069792"),
    "numExtents" : 8945,
    "nindexes" : 3,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1.0000000000008387,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : NumberLong("5760211476544"),
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : NumberLong("2696098227536"),
            "a_1_m_1__t_1" : 1096589803344,
            "a_1_ui_1__t_1" : NumberLong("1967523445664")
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

My questions are:

- Is Mongo supposed to write on the space freed by deleted records, or will it keep using new space?
- Can I run repair database, or do I need a lot more free space for that?
- Can I run compact and will it help (the padding factor is pretty much 1.0 as it is)? How much free space do I need to run compact?
- Is there anything else I can do to buy more time or free up space?

Thanks,

Oz

Comment: On a side note, which compression are you using? Are you aware about the [zlib](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-compression-options-mongodb-30) compression?

Comment: Also, [according to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14478248/2278844), repair requires 2X the size of your collection.

Comment: @CydrickT I wasn't aware of the zlib. I'll try to check it out, but we're using MongoDB v2.4.6, and I'm not sure I can upgrade it.

Still - isn't mongo supposed to write on the deleted records' space first (or at any time, at least)?

Comment: that, I have no idea.